# Are bounties supposed to be a "only high rep" thing?

Tags: discussion, bounty

Today I have looked into the bounty feature and saw that 50 is the smallest amount of reputation you can give. As a beginner this would cost me 50% of my reputation - so it is very unlikely that I use this feature in near future/ever.

Is it designed/wanted that low reputation users are unlikely to use it? If yes, what is the reasoning behind that?

Comment: To some extent, I suppose this is to prevent a flood of bounties on low-quality questions by new users.

Comment: I don't think that it was designed with blocking out low-rep users in mind, but with incentivizing high-rep users to answer questions. You can already give 10 points to an answer if you can upvote, so placing a bounty really needs to be more than this amount for it to offer any real incentive.

Comment: @Hans Passant so its partly about earning the use

Comment: Considering that  you could put a bounty on a question now if you wanted to, but you just don't want to, you would have to consider yourself a high rep user to think that only high rep users can use bounties.  Do you consider 115 rep a high rep user?  I know I don't, but that's just me.  That you value your rep more than having a bounty is your personal choice.

Comment: @Servy I propably used the wrong words for that. My intent was that people with for example 10k reputation propably don't even feel these 50 reputation. Hence no desicion there anymore.

Comment: @Servy people with many reputation points can post a bounty and not experience reduced permissions on the site; that is not true of a user with less than 300 rep (except for a brief gap between 175 and 200 rep).  It is true that it's still each user's choice, but you can't deny there are exaggerated costs at the low end.

Comment: @Gus And yet I expect you'll find a significant percentage of bounties come from such users.  The kinds of people that get tens of thousands of rep on SO tend to be the types of people who can figure problems out on their own.

Comment: thank you for showing me that dupe - I truly didn't find it. In difference to that dupe, my question was truly not meant as a rant. I just was curious if  the effect perceived by me was the one that it was designed for and why.

Comment: @blackmiaool very interesting thank you. Now I am really interested in the statistics of bounty usage in correlation to user reputation. But I don't dare to ask haha.

Comment: @Rhayene  The url I posted is wrong. This one: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4700219/alexander-hein  spent his whole rep(350) to make a bounty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it designed/wanted that low reputation users are unlikely to use it?

Well, it comes with some cost, the [minimum rep to place a bounty is 75](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) (which isn't really *high rep*). The OP needs to make a decision if they think the bountied question is worth their reputation loss.

> If yes, what is the reasoning behind that?

The reasoning is to prevent the featured page getting spammed with low quality questions, where the OP thinks they'll need an urgent answer.

Comment: I have forgotten how many crap you guys have to wade through every day. Now I feel bad to have added another crap question, just because I was curious.

Comment: @Rhayene, nope, your question isn't crap. Asking about what something was designed for is absolutely OK if a question isn't a dupe and if there's no answer in the Help Center.